# What does the Shining Example Gift actually do?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, werewolf-the-forsaken

What does this ability do?
"For the rest of the scene, the werewolf can change a resisted
or contested action (WoD Core p130) into an instant action."
(Full text at bottom).

It sounds something like a demon ability: Swift Resolution   (Demon: The Descent -- Page 178), but more limited. (Obviously we are not talking about nwod-2e, but still perhaps these abilities have the same author or inspiration)

Resisted actions are not defined in WoD core, but presumably it is an ability
that is activated like "Roll X+Y - target's Z", and also is non-instant, like either begin explicitly extended ("each roll represents 5 minutes of X"), or explicitly taking a long time: "This ability may be activated after doing X for 5 minutes"

**To be clear: what is a Resisted Action, for purposed of this gift**

Contest actions are more well defined, and when there are extended (which they can be), then it more or less makes perfect sense.

But there are still some questions:

**Does it actually change the time required? Is it now done in 3 seconds?**
So for example if done to a foot chase -- a extended contested. A single Dex+Athletics roll would me made, either the chased would be caught, or the chaser would give up, in 3 seconds?

**Can a extended action be made contested by competing?**
Rules on page 130 make it sound that way.
Eg two people might have a race to carve a garden gnome out of wood.
This is now a contested action so the ability can be used?

> ### [Honor 4 ]   Shining Example   ( Signs Of The Moon -- Page 103 )
>
> **Cost**: 1 Willpower 
> **Dice Pool**: Presence + Occult + Honor 
> **Action**: Reflexive 
> An
> honorable werewolf can't rest on her laurels. Others have to see her
> being honest and impartial, putting them ahead of herself, and doing
> her duty to her pack and her totem. Sometimes, that's hard. Uncovering
> taint is never easy, but it's worse when she discovers her own alpha
> is a Bale Hound. Negotiating with a powerful spirit is an exhausting
> ordeal, but all most people will ever know is that tomorrow is much
> the same as today. Carrying the flame of truth is hard, especially
> when it's a truth most people would wish buried. Fortunately, just as
> the Elunim give Half Moons the ability to channel their honor backed
> with spiritual power, they empower particularly honorable behavior. A
> werewolf can use this Gift after performing a notable feat of honor.
> **Dramatic Failure:** The Elunim turn their shadowed faces to the
> character. Whether they misunderstood her motives or see some flaw of
> which she is not yet aware, their displeasure is clear. The character
> loses a point of Essence. Failure: The character fails to impress the
> spirits. 
> **Success** The werewolf's deeds impress the Elunim, showing
> that she is willing to put everything aside to do what is clearly
> right. For the rest of the scene, the werewolf can change a resisted
> or contested action (WoD Core p130) into an instant action. She can do
> this a number of times equal to her Honor Renown. 
> **Exceptional Success:**
> The character regains two points of Essence in addition to the effects
> of a success.

Comment: Cross Posted to: http://forum.theonyxpath.com/forum/main-category/main-forum/the-new-world-of-darkness/werewolf-the-forsaken/262779-what-does-the-shining-example-gift-actually-do

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if it's drawing a distinction between Contested and Instant actions, the implication is that the user of this Gift gets to ignore the contesting individual's participation. The example of an instant action in the Core Rulebook is a man trying to catch his grandmother's China Doll (Dexterity + Athletics with a - 3 penalty for a room full of furniture). The example of a contested action, however, is two individuals, Karen and a mugger, both running from a werewolf (each roll Dexterity + Athletics, with one receiving both a bonus and penalty for circumstances). This would imply that the distinction is whether there is another participant. Therefore, it seems that this Gift allows the user to *ignore* outside interference in their actions. For instance, in the mugger situation above, if Karen were a werewolf who had satisfied the requirements of this Gift, she would roll once while the mugger would not roll at all. Thus, one success would "win" the contest.

Resisted action, likewise, probably means what you presume: an action where the other individual (the victim of an attack, perhaps) gets to subtract some attribute or skill from your roll. This would, then, be ignored. You are, however, right, in your assertion that it isn't specifically defined as such, and certainly not in the reference given.

Finally, the question of whether this changes the time necessary to perform the action. Would this, for instance, mean that a foot race is over in 3 seconds? It does say "*change* a resisted or contested action (WoD Core p130) into an instant action." which would, by strict interpretation, mean it would always take one action to perform. Remember that Gifts are magic and, therefore, not bound by natural laws or expectations, so this is a perfectly valid interpretation.

Having said that, I'm inclined, personally, to say that it's probably meant to be interpreted that outcome of the the action is *decided* in a single roll, and that the action itself still takes whatever amount of time it would have taken, mostly because this prevents awkward and confusing situations.

To summarize: this Gift seems to allow the Werewolf to all but irgnore those who would stand in her way.